# ver en que directorio estoy (PWD) en ruby

Tags: ruby

Estoy aprendiendo ruby, así que estoy haciendo varios programas que ya había hecho en python para practicar el lenguaje (porque no se me ocurren muchas cosas que pueda hacer, si a alguien se le ocurre algún ejercicio de programación en ruby por favor escriba lo en los comentarios.) en estos momentos estoy recreando un proyecto que era un emulador de de bash en windows, para eso ocupo poner un prompt que tenga el directorio en el que se encuentre el usuario.

¿como puedo saber en que directorio me encuentro usando ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el *path* absoluto:

```
Dir.pwd
```

Para el *path* relativo al script que está siendo ejecutado:

```
__dir__
```